# Как отследить изменившееся значение sessionStorage и поместить в переменную?

Tags: javascript, jquery

В [проекте](https://cloud.mail.ru/home/project/) есть таблица Bootstrap, состоящая из трех колонок. Подключен плагин [colresizable](http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/) для того чтобы иметь возможность изменять ширину колонок таблицы. И для того чтобы сохранять измененные ширины колонок таблицы пользователем, в скрипте включено свойство **postbackSafe**, которое сохраняет все изменения в **sessionStorage**. И вот вопрос, допустим пользователь изменил ширину колонок, и какие-то значения в **sessionStorage** поменялись, как  отследить изменившиеся там значения и поместить в переменную?

```js
$("#flex").colResizable({
  liveDrag: true,
  resizeMode: 'flex',
  postbackSafe: true
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Resizable columns -->
<script src="https://rawgit.com/alvaro-prieto/colResizable/master/colResizable-1.6.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <h2>Bordered Table</h2>
  <p>The .table-bordered class adds borders to a table:</p>
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="flex">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, вам не надо следить за **sessionStorage**. В плагине есть событие изменения ширины `onResize`. Вот на него и подписывайтесь, получайте значение ширины, записывайте в переменную.

Пример из документации:

```
$(function(){

  var onSampleResized = function(e){  
    var table = $(e.currentTarget); //reference to the resized table
  };  

  $("#flex").colResizable({
     liveDrag: true,
     resizeMode: 'flex',
     postbackSafe: true,
     onResize: onSampleResized
  });

});
```

Пример вычисления ширины.

```js
function onSampleResized(e) {
  var $table = $(e.currentTarget);
  console.clear();
  $table.find('th').each(function(i) {
    console.log(`column: ${i}; width: ${$(this).width()}`);
  });
}
$("#flex").colResizable({
  liveDrag: true,
  resizeMode: 'flex',
  postbackSafe: true,
  onResize: onSampleResized
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Resizable columns -->
<script src="https://rawgit.com/alvaro-prieto/colResizable/master/colResizable-1.6.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <h2>Bordered Table</h2>
  <p>The .table-bordered class adds borders to a table:</p>
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="flex">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: И все же, как можно отследить **sessionStorage** и поместить его в переменную, который постоянно меняется при изменении ширины колонок таблицы?

Comment: @Nick Зачем вам отслеживать **sessionStorage**?

Answer (score -1):

В хроме можно посмотреть с каким ключом и значением сохраняется.

Получить можно через

```
let variable = sessionStorage.getItem('key')
```

[API документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]